# Installing 'pandas' into Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I recently cloned a repository from GitHub. But when I tried to run it with Pycharm, there was an error that said that no module called pandas was available. So I went to my project interpreter and tried to add pandas to the interpreter, but for some reason it failed to install. The error was 'collect2: error: Id returned 1 exit status'. Is there a way to install the pandas package into my project interpreter in Pycharm? Thanks.

EDIT: So I made a new discovery after the suggestion to check the pip version. I opened up another virtual environment project interpreter that's 3.5 instead of 3.6, and I managed to install pandas on that one. I want to stick with my 3.6 project interpreter, so is there a way to get it installed on there or do I have no choice but to downgrade?

Comment: 'pip install pandas' from the command prompt.

PyCharm monitors your Python instance in real time and will immediately identify that Pandas has been installed.

Comment: You mean the Terminal, right? I'm using Linux by the way. I did what you suggested just now and the interpreter still won't install pandas. Do I need to restart the computer?

Comment: pandas uses cython extensions, which have to be compiled.. the error you show looks like something went wrong in the compilation. i don't know how to fix it, but maybe you could install anaconda instead (python + a lot of modules prebuilt)?

Comment: Type 'pip -V' in the terminal.  Make sure the python version you see there is the same as the configured project interpreter in PyCharm.  You might not be installing pandas to the version of Python you think you are.

Comment: The pip version i have is python 3.5. The project interpreter is 3.6.

Comment: Either change your project interpreter in PyCharm to 3.5 or point PIP to 3.6 and install Pandas again.  Pointing PyCharm to 3.5 is what I'd do.